# Chrome Extension setting httpOnly cookie not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension. where I set the cookie for our website using Chrome Extension code. Following was my previous code this was working before (note this code was in content js file):

```
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";Max-Age=7200;path=/";
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";Max-Age=7200;path=/" + ";domain=" + domain;
```

But after getting issue, I also added code in backgroundJs file, below is my code:

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": cookieName,
    "domain": domain,
    "value": cookieValue,
    "path": "/",
    "url": 'https://www.mywebsite.com/',
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": true,
}, function (cookie) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

I can see my cookie setting in browser, but on page load that is getting changed with server's own cookie value.
Is there any workaround so that I can set my cookie value to that cookie.

Thanks

Comment: `but on page load that is getting changed with server's own cookie value` - well of course, because the server is sending a cookie, so the browser does its job

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve and what exactly issues you have.

Comment: @Bravo I am developing a group buy tool of a website so that my users can use the website without buying subscription to that website. I developed this chrome extension 1 year ago and it was working perfectly fine till last week. what i do is i generate a new server side cookie via selenium scraping and store that cookie in my database as well as setup same cookie on my client's browsers.so now when cookie at server and at client were same so it was working fine.but now somehow this client cookie which is set in the browser is ignored by the server hence it generates a new cookie

Comment: @hindmost please read above comment. maybe its clear now. as server ignores browser cookie, it keeps on generating new cookie and my users goes in infinite loop.

Comment: @user1400290 really, how interesting - but when you load a page, and the server sends a cookie, the browser will accept that cookie - not sure of the significance of the other 109 words in your comment

Comment: AFAIU you're trying to replace 3rd-party site's cookie, but the external server ignores your cookie value and set new value. Most likely that's because browser does _not actually send_ your cookie value to the server. The reasons may vary: wrong domain, expiration date, host permissions etc.